# JavaScript - Getting value of data attribute returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a `data-time` attribute that holds an integer value fetched from my database. I get the value of it but it returns undefined. I inspected the browser and my data-time attribute stores the value correctly.
It is really strange because I am doing the same thing before that and it doesn't return undefined. Here is my code:

```
<option data-price="{{ $availableOption->price * $course }}" data-time="{{ $availableOption->delivery_time }}">
...
</option
```

Script

```
$('.config-option option:selected').each(function() {
    var currentElement = $('this');
    var optionDeliveryTimeStr = currentElement.attr('data-time');
    console.log(optionDeliveryTimeStr);
});
```

I do the exact same thing before that with the data-price attribute and it returns the value as string. But it doesn't work with the data-time attribute. If someone could offer a solution and an explanation I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is this line

```
 var currentElement = $('this');
```

remove quotes from `this` and replace it with

```
 var currentElement = $(this);
```

Comment: Yes it did. I have it correctly with data-price but didn't notice I wrote quotes with the second data attribute.

Comment: Also consider jQuery has a another method for getting data atts `.data('time')`.

Comment: @Andy many time this `data` method doesn't work especially when this attribute is set dynamically at later stage than element creation. So, I would rather suggest to keep it simply since OP hasn't mentioned how this attribute is created.

Answer (score 0):

Use $(currentElement) instead of currentElement:

```
$('.config-option option:selected').each(function() {
    var currentElement = $(this);
    var optionDeliveryTimeStr = $(currentElement).attr('data-time'); // OR $(currentElement).data('time');
    console.log(optionDeliveryTimeStr);
});
```

Comment: `$(currentElement).attr('data-time');` == `$($(this)).attr('data-time');` ?